# Custom Zoom Control Results In Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to change the zoom increment when using Google Maps JavaScript API on iOS. For example, instead of going from zoom 14 to zoom 15, I would like for it to go straight to zoom 16 and then zoom 18, and so on... when a user uses the pinch to zoom gesture.

I know I can achieve this with buttons, but I can't seem to find a solution for pinch to zoom gesture. I realize that the `zoom_changed` event needs to be tracked.

I get an error of `Maximum call stack size exceeded` with `map.setZoom(zoom + 2);` and `map.setZoom(zoom - 2);` when added on line 17 and 19, respectively.

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2zmn9173/4/. This is the part I need help with:

```
if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        if (map.getZoom() > zoom) {
            alert("ZOOMED IN from Level " + zoom);
        } else if (map.getZoom() < zoom) {
            alert("ZOOMED OUT from Level " + zoom);
        }
        zoom = map.getZoom();
    });
}
```

The buttons on top demonstrate the functionality I am trying to achieve, but with pinch to zoom gesture.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach:

only set a new zoom when the current zoom is not a even number(this should stop the infinite loop)

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function(){
      var z=this.getZoom();
      if(z%2){//when zoom is a odd number
        var fx=((!isNaN(this.get('z'))&&this.get('z')<z))?2:0;
        this.setZoom(Math.floor(z/2)*2+fx);
      }else{
        this.set('z',z);
      }
    });
```

---

### Demo:

```js
function initialize() {
  var ctrl = document.getElementById('zoom');
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.549,
        13.425),
      noClear: true
    }),


    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(ctrl);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var z = this.getZoom();
    if (z % 2) { //when zoom is a odd number
      var fx = ((!isNaN(this.get('z')) && this.get('z') < z)) ? 2 : 0;
      this.setZoom(Math.floor(z / 2) * 2 + fx);
    } else {
      this.set('z', z);
    }
    ctrl.innerHTML = this.getZoom();
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'zoom_changed');
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#zoom {
  font: bold 2em Monospace;
  background: tomato;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas">
  <div id="zoom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle. This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you add those lines where you are pointing in your question, You will be firing the event `zoom_changed` inside the event `zoom_changed`, this will create a stackoverflow because it will never end firing the events.

```
if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        if (map.getZoom() > zoom) {
            map.setZoom(zoom + 2); //This will trigger "zoom_changed" again
        } else if (map.getZoom() < zoom) {
            map.setZoom(zoom - 2); //This will trigger "zoom_changed" again
        }
        zoom = map.getZoom();
    });
}
```

And `zoom = map.getZoom();` will change the zoom afterwards, but the other events will be already executed, my suggestion, is set a value, and call `setZoom` afterwards:

```
if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        var newZoom = map.getZoom(), oldZoom = zoom;
        if (newZoom > oldZoom) {
            oldZoom + 2;
        } else if (newZoom < oldZoom) {
            oldZoom - 2;
        }
        zoom = oldZoom;
        map.setZoom(oldZoom);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting the same error. Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2zmn9173/6/. Shouldn't `oldZoom + 2` and `oldZoom -2` should be inside `map.setZoom();`? Using the `alert` tags, I can see the zoom incrementing by 2, but it is not being set on the map.