# Zoom In and Out of Google Maps based on Increments of 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I earlier asked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886371/custom-zoom-control-results-in-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error) question which had a great solution (see below), but now I am wondering if it's possible to modify the zoom in and out levels of Google Maps API so that the map changes based on increments of 3 as the `zoom_changed` event is triggered?

This solution from the previous thread worked well for increments of 2:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function(){
    var z = this.getZoom();
    if (z % 2) { //when zoom is a odd number
        var fx = ((!isNaN(this.get('z')) && this.get('z') < z)) ? 2:0;
        this.setZoom(Math.floor(z / 2) * 2 + fx);
    } else {
        this.set('z', z);
    }
});
```

An example JSFiddle is **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxf18wLw/)**.

Edit: So the above code works if 2 is replaced by 3. But one thing I'm struggling with is setting the initial zoom to 11. It does not work. Defaults to 9 if zoom rate is 3, or defaults to 10 if zoom rate is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy change the zoom rate
If you assign the rate ath the var zoom_rate you can easy change the configuration see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/33qskxdg/

```
    function initialize() {


      var zoom_rate = 3    // assign the zoom rate

      var ctrl = document.getElementById('zoom');
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.549,
            13.425),
          noClear: true
        }),


        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(ctrl);

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        var z = this.getZoom();
        if (z % zoom_rate) { //when zoom is a odd number
          var fx = ((!isNaN(this.get('z')) && this.get('z') < z)) ? zoom_rate : 0;
          this.setZoom(Math.floor(z / zoom_rate) * zoom_rate + fx);
        } else {
          this.set('z', z);
        }
        ctrl.innerHTML = this.getZoom();
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'zoom_changed');
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Hmm, when I tried this I ended up getting `maximum call stack size exceeded` errors. Thank you for this. I am looking into it.

Comment: In fiddle this not happen .. .. i have tried the code and in my env with firefox work .. right..  work fine from 0 to 21 -- scrool wheel and control

Comment: One thing I'm struggling with is setting the initial zoom to 11. It does not work. Defaults to 9 if zoom rate is 3, or defaults to 10 if zoom rate is 2.

Comment: 11 is not a multiple of 2 or 3, your algorithm won't allow it.

Comment: Can the algorithm be modified to accommodate that? It is not my algorithm but from another user based on the thread I linked in my question.

Comment: Yes the algorithm can be modiified but for me is not clear what you want obtain .. you need only that the start zoom is eleven and that is not redefined by a multiple of 3.. In you sample was 14  the init zoom .. let me know

Comment: Yes, sorry that was my mistake. I'd like the map to start at zoom 11 and then zoom in / out based on increments of 3.